# Windows 10 UWP - How to preload a page before displaying it?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

I'm working on a Windows 10 app that involves using a lot of images. As it stands, navigating from one page to another results in a few seconds of "pop-in" as the various images on the page load and the result is rather janky

So TL;DR - *Is it possible to preload the contents of a page before displaying it to the user so that the transition from page x to page y is smooth?*

I've tried googling for a solution but whether its the wrong vernacular I'm using or it can't be done, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to preload the contents of a page before displaying it to the user so that the transition from page x to page y is smooth?

In an UWP app, before a Page is loaded, [Frame.Navigate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) must be called. There should have some actions in this method, for example: Allocate memory, Load resource, Rendering. So for your Scenario, in my view, it is impossible to preload the resource of a Page before showing them.

Avoiding using the images with huge size is a possible solution. Or, if you just want to load a lot of small images,

> You can bind list controls to arbitrarily large data sources, and still achieve high performance, by using incremental loading.

When you need to load a lot of images in one page, the right way to do this is using [ISupportIncrementalLoading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx) with Data binding. You can refer to [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx).

Here is the official [XAML data binding sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5), scenario 8 is about incremental loading. Although is this a windows 8.1 app, this method can be used also in a UWP app.

I wrote a simple [IncrementalLoading](http://1drv.ms/1JZfi2a) demo here, it just uses a `GridView` and `Image` inside it to load and show 1000 images in one page.

Comment: I should specify that the images I am loading are attached to UI Elements as background properties. For example, buttons.

Comment: @MasterDex ok, How did you store your images? Where? And could you please post a screen shot of your page which you want to preload?

Answer (score 0):

You friend is the `Loaded` event, will be fired after the `UIElement` got loaded in the view..

you can do somethings like: by default, the images list is `Opacity` = 0, and set the loaded event: images list `Opacity` = 1..
by that, you can make sure that the list is invisible until it get loaded :)